Toggling Between Git Branches in Spyder
I'm using Spyder as my main IDE and I would like to be able to switch branches from within the IDE, as opposed to switching branches within the terminal and closing/reopening the Spyder app.
Does anyone know how to do this, or if it is even possible? The documentation given on the Spyder website is prohibitively sparse and I haven't been able to figure it out just by playing around in the IDE.
